# Using static variables with durable functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a long running function that i want to convert to a durable function.
The workflow is:

- get config values (conn strings) and keys from key vault & store in static variables.
- call second function that uses these values to connect to a service, get data and store in a database.

Complete run time is a few minutes so it is too long for regular azure functions.
If i convert this to durable functions:

- is it incorrect to use static variables at the static class level? I am doing this as one function populates the variables and then the next function uses them.
  I understand durable functions can restart any time, and so would my
  static variables be emptied if this happened?
- Is it incorrect to call static helper methods in a durable function? e.g. a method to build a string?

Answer (score 1):

> is it incorrect to use static variables at the static class level? I
> am doing this as one function populates the variables and then the
> next function uses them. I understand durable functions can restart
> any time, and so would my static variables be emptied if this
> happened?

In general I think it would be incorrect.
You should communicate necessary data to activities and sub-orchestrators through input/output.

> Is it incorrect to call static helper methods in a durable function?
> e.g. a method to build a string?

Do you mean in an orchestrator function?
It is ok as long as the static method is deterministic and does not do anything else not allowed in an orchestrator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what about calling a static method from an activity method , i.e. an activity method that reads data from a service then calls a static method to save that data to a database?

Comment: That can be ok but it depends. If you use for example a static HttpClient, you can run into issues with DNS changes not being respected. Typically in .NET Functions, you would setup your services in DI and inject them into the function object, and use HttpClientFactory for any HTTP services.